# Methods for showing homology of a subgroup survives to the larger group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-homology

Suppose we have an inclusion of groups $G_1<G_2$. I am curious about what methods there are out there for analyzing the map $H_k(G_1;\mathbb Q)\to H_k(G_2;\mathbb Q)$. In particular, what are tools that might show it is injective? In several of the cases I'm interested in, $G_1\cong\mathbb Z^k$. I.e. I want to show that the top dimensional homology of a certain free abelian subgroup survives to the whole group.

**Edit:** One example I'm thinking about is abelian subgroups of the mapping class group of a surface generated by disjoint Dehn twists. I know for example, that in a torus with $4k+1$ punctures, that the subgroup generated by $4k+1$ Dehn twists along curves which cut the torus into $4k+1$ punctured annuli has a fundamental class that survives to the whole mapping class group. The method of showing this is rather indirect (constructing an explicit cocycle detecting it in the ribbon graph complex), so a more conceptual explanation would be nice.

The other main class of examples come from subgroups of $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$, as explained in [this paper.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02351)

Comment: Well, the most obvious case in which this happens is when $G_1$ is a retract.  If $G_2$ happens to be *virtually special* and $G_1$ is quasiconvex then $G_1$ is always  *virtual* retract of $G_2$, so one can then try to analyse how 'virtual' the retract really is.

Comment: @HJRW: A retract seems way too much to hope for in the cases I'm thinking about, but your answer serves as a motivation to learn about virtually special groups.

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you indicated which cases you do have in mind.

Comment: @HJRW: fair enough. I was hoping to assemble a toolkit of general methods, but I will add some more information about the examples I'm thinking about.

Comment: If your subgroup is normal then there is the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence. If it's of finite index, there's the transfer. Both of these are explained in Brown's book.